# Eclipse Executable Jar Resource Files

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, export, executable-jar

I would like to export my Java program, but I have run into problems. It exports fine but my resource files like my res folder and my sound folder aren't there. They are located in the project directory, so I don't know if that should be a problem. I am currently just using `ImageIcon().getImage()` to get my pictures and that works fine but when I export and run it the program runs but it doesn't have any pictures. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: have you tried it? Did it work?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that once the images/sounds are inside the jar you must access them as a resource.

```
Image image = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/image.gif")).getImage();
```

Make sure the images are really inside the jar opening the jar with winrar or similar if not add the folders as source folders in your buildpath.

Comment: Ok I am really sorry for the delay. I just got it yesterday after raging haha. Thanks dude, I actually did it exactly like this.